# Animate table view performFetch like the missed calls in the iPhone phone app

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

I have a UISegmentedController that controls a TableView.
when the selectedIndex is switched I am preforming a performFetch method with a new predicate that causes a change in the tableView content.

it works fine but i want it to animate in the same style that apple did in the phone application when you switch between all recents and only un answered calls.

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K managed to do that -

I dont Know how apple do that but i seceded when i have realized that preforming new fetch is more expensive operation then that -

**step 1:**
in my case i have added a mutableArray that collects all the indexes of the cells i want to disappear when the user clicks the segmented controller.

in the CellForRaw function i inserted this little code:

```
- (void)configureCell:(PersonCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Configure the cell
    if([fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]!=nil){
    Person *person = (Person *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.person = person;
    cell.delegate=self;

        if (person.state!=0) {
            [activeIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
}
```

that inserts the indexPath of the objects i want to filter to the Array for later use.

**step 2:**
the next function is called when a change made in the segmentedController -

```
-(void)ReloadTableViewWithNewPerdicate:(id)sender{

    UISegmentedControl *sc = (UISegmentedControl*)sender;
    //[theTableView beginUpdates];
    Person *person;
    switch (sc.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 1:
            for (int i=0; i<[activeIndexPaths count]; i++) {
                person=(Person*)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[activeIndexPaths objectAtIndex:i]];
                [fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext deleteObject:person];
            }

            //[theTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:activeIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;
        case 0:
            [fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext rollback];
            break;

    }
```

This function delete the raws from the fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext 
and the:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller{
}
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
}
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
}
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
}
```

functions are responsible for deleting the un needed raws.
and this is basically how you get the effect of the deletion.

**step 3:**
when the user taps the main segmentedController button the function calls:

```
            [fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext rollback];
```

that literally  rolls everything back.

**step 4:**
Last importent step is to add the rollBack  function to the ViewWillDisAppear to make sure that the save function in your app delegate wont save the changes and delete the raws from the store.

hope it will help someone.

good day.

Comment: Wow, that's some really dirty hacking! I hoped to find a solution for showing / hiding rows using NSFetchedResultsController (as performFetch:) doesn't inform the delegate. But this code is really a hack!

Comment: I Hope you will inform me if you will find something more elegant. BTW this Hack works great :).

Comment: Hello @shannoga is it possible to use this animation without coredata or any more way to do this.

Comment: any other way to do same animation?